# Can I open a minimized app in the system tray via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We have an application running on our RemoteApp Server. When the application starts, it's automatically minimized to the system tray. This Application has no command line tools to make it start without minimizing to the system tray.

A user which works with the RemoteApps needs this application, but he can't see it since the app gets minimized to the system tray of the server, he can't see that on his machine.

Is there a way to open minimized apps in the system tray via powershell?

I know the `shell.application` ComObject, but that doesn't help me in this case. Can this be achieved with PowerShell? Do I need a `win32 Native function` for this?

I really could not find anything on google. the only thing I found were about notify icons etc.

Comment: Apps don't really "minimize to the system tray". Some apps may *choose* to create a notification icon in the notification area (proper name for the "system tray") but how/why they do so is entirely within their control and not standardized. If you've found code for interaction with notification icons, that's what you need but there aren't any *standard protocols* you can rely upon to interact with them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hmm ok. thanks for your explanation. well whenever I double click the notify icon the application is visible on the screen, and on the taskbar. if I minimize it manually, it's not visible anymore and also not visible in the taskbar, only the notify icon is visible. The only code I found is about how to create a notifyicon in PowerShell, not how to interact with them. Well i'll take a closer look but i'm not very positive about finding something useful.

Comment: I'm using a trayrestore function in autohotkey: it enumerates the shell tray control and sends a single or double click. My point is that it's certainly possible via WINAPI native functions so you can find the existing code in another language and use it as a reference when writing your own.